# Mysql Error 1130: Unknown domain connecting to my server

Tags: php, mysql, connection, dreamhost, mysql-error-1130

I noticed an odd mysql error while testing a prototype site(containing php and a mysql database) for a client and it has me worried/confused. Forgive me if this is a simple or obvious question but I have not been able to find articles that adequately explain this.

---

**Situation:**
While clicking through the site I received the following error message:
"Connect Error (1130) Host 'kingdomofkicks.co.uk' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server"

This is confusing because "kingdomofkicks.co.uk' means absolutely nothing to me. For the record our site is hosted on Dreamhost.com.

The php/mysql code that threw the error is:

```
  //connect to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");
    //If any errors occur, kill the script and display the error. 
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
```

The site was working fine prior to this error and after a refresh it seems to be working just fine now.

Furthermore, I looked into the mysql server to see if there is anything that odd and noticed that the user was listed as [myusername]@kingdomofkicks.co.uk. I never noticed this prior to now.

---

**My questions:**

1. What happened that caused this error to be displayed?
2. Is this something that I need to be worried about? In particular since my mysql user appears to be listed under this domain now.
3. Is there something that I can do to defend/protect against this in the future?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Check the reverse DNS of your server IP. If it's a shared server, it may have reverse DNS for many or all the domains that are hosted on the server.

Comment: @Barmar I did it using debouncer.com/reverse-dns-check and got the following output: "FCrDNS test result:
208.113.247.162 resolved to apache2-noxim.rygar.dreamhost.com. 
apache2-noxim.rygar.dreamhost.com resolved to 208.113.247.162; 
rDNS if forward confirmed.

Dynamic IP test result:
apache2-noxim.rygar.dreamhost.com not looks like dynamic IP address."  Any thoughts on what that teaches me?

Comment: Maybe it was a temporary DNS problem that they've fixed.